# Flag raised since more than 2 weeks and still pending, what to do?

Tags: support, flags

First at all I thank the moderator for their time energy and patience to moderate, and I perfectly understand they need time to react when a flag is raised.

I put 2 times a flag on a given answer 'disturbing' me. The first time a moderator reacted very fast removing remarks associated to the answer and editing the answer itself. The day after the author of the answer canceled purely and simply the moderator modification on the answer, so I put again a flag on it. I did April 5 and since the flag is pending.

Of course I cannot know the reason of that delay, I know nothing about the hidden flag management, I do not know if the moderators are 'playing the watch' and the 'rotting of the flag', but that does not suit me, I have not raised two times a flag on this answer for nothing.

What can I do in these conditions ?

Comment: Which site did you raise the flag on, and which sort of flag did you raise? Rude, NAA, VLQ, or what?

Comment: @CertainPerformance on https://stackoverflow.com/ ( more precisely on that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026491/how-to-update-pointers-when-pushed-on-to-stdstack-using-iteration/61032166#61032166 ), I did not use the rude/... but 'other' like I did the first time

Comment: Custom flags often enough take a *looong* time to get processed.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  yes 'custom' sorry I do not flag enough to remember naming :-) Yes, but just needed few minutes the first time and now more than 2 weeks. So what can I do ?

Comment: There are 1000 flags raised per day for mods to look at. The flag queue lacks some filtering / sorting. Mods get to your flag eventually. It can take 6 to 8 weeks. I consider flags to be "fire and forget". Sitting on your flag page waiting for a flag to be handled is a waste of your time.

Comment: @rene 1000 per day, incredible. Thank you for your answer

Comment: This seems more a question or concern about a specific flag on a specific site rather than a general question about what to do in every instance - which is a better form of the question. Where a user has a specific complaint about moderation or 'how a site is being run' they **should bring the matter up** ***on their own meta*** and only come to M.SE to attempt to appeal the outcome. It would seem that the answer **is** that you raise flags for work you should do, and you should know this at your level. You are fortunate not to be flag banned, and only ignored.

Comment: @Rob ok thank you for your remark, in fact I put the question here because when I search for a question about the same subject I found them here (this was more than 10 days ago, I waited to put that question because in answers to the other question people said one week is classically needed for the moderation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could have rolled back the rollback yourself; [I have done so now.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61032166/revisions) If the author continues to revert those changes, it will lead to more (automatic) flags, and *eventually* the ♦ moderators will get to it. There's no 'flag rot' on these kind of flags, but you can help reduce the workload by performing some moderating actions yourself. Remember what the [sidebar widget on the review pages says](https://stackoverflow.com/review/):

> Stack Overflow is moderated by [you](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your edit, I did not wanted to do that myself because I am concerned and do not want to be 'judge & party'

Comment: For your first flag, that's 100% the way to go. However, now that a ♦ moderator made a decision, it's fine to enforce it yourself.

Comment: Ok that is clear, thank you again